# Do I have to archive a build for my app and widgetkit extension separately to share with TestFlight?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, testflight, widgetkit

I just finished up my widget and I want to archive it for TestFlight however I cannot find the answer on how i'm supposed to build the app and the widgetkit extension? Do I first select the app target and archive then the widget target and archive or will archiving the app archive the app as well?

I went through [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html) but i'm still confused.

Comment: If you archive the main app, the widget extension is included in the build. You don't have to make separate builds or anything like that.

Comment: What @West1 said. I might add one thing - if a WidgetKit extension is anything like a Photos Editing Extension, you *will* needs a separate bundle identifier. (For me that meant a rejection, but all I needed was "com.mycompany.app" for the main app and "com.mycompany.app.extension" for the extension. The rejection was very clear about what I needed to do.))

Comment: @dfd yes that’s actually now a warning in xcode !